# Remove rectangles from PDF file

Tags: java, pdf

I'd like to have a program that removes all rectangles from a PDF file. One use case for this is to unblacken a given PDF file to see if there is any hidden information behind the rectangles. The rest of the PDF file should be kept as-is.

Which PDF library is suitable to this task? In Java, I would like the code to look like this:

```
PdfDocument doc = PdfDocument.load(new File("original.pdf"));
PdfDocument unblackened = doc.transform(new CopyingPdfVisitor() {
  public void visitRectangle(PdfRect rect) {
    if (rect.getFillColor().getBrightness() >= 0.1) {
      super.visitRectangle(rect);
    }
  }
});
unblackened.save(new File("unblackened.pdf"));
```

The `CopyingPdfVisitor` would copy a PDF document exactly as-is, and my custom code would leave out all the dark rectangles.

Comment: Itext has not yet implemented everything possible along the lines of vector graphics. You might in this respect be more happy with PDFBox.

Answer (score 0):

Itext pdf library have ways to modify pdf content.

The *ITEXT CONTENTPARSER Example * may give you any idea. "qname" parameter (qualified name) may be used to detected rectangle element.

http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=15

Other option, if you want obtain the text on the document use the PdfReaderContentParser to extract text content

```
public void parsePdf(String pdf, String txt) throws IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(txt));
    TextExtractionStrategy strategy;
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        strategy = parser.processContent(i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
        out.println(strategy.getResultantText());
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

example at http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=277